# CompareTo not allowing to compare two objects

Tags: java, compareto

So I am looking to sort an array list of objects based on a field in the object but I am getting an error "Cannot resolve method compareTo(int)"

```
            ArrayList<SuperHero> herolistClone = (ArrayList<SuperHero>) superheroList.clone();
            Collections.sort(herolistClone, new Comparator<SuperHero>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(SuperHero superHero, SuperHero superHeroTwo) {
                    return   superHero.getCiviliansSaved().compareTo(superHeroTwo.getCiviliansSaved());
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `getCiviliansSaved()` returns an int? ints are not objects, thus, cannot be dereferenced (the 'dot' operator cannot be applied to them).

Try `Integer.compare(superHero.getCiviliansSaved(), superHeroTwo.getCiviliansSaved());`

Or, replace all of it with modern, shiny new java:

`heroListClone.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(SuperHero::getCiviliansSaved));`

boom, more readable, and turned 5 complicated lines into a single one.

I'm predicting you want to reverse the sort (list the hero that saved the most, at the 0 position in your list), in which case, just slap a `.reversed()` at the end there, right before the last `);`.